# How to reply page post comment via personal message - api.ai chatbot

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, chatbot, dialogflow-es

I have a requirement in which when a user comment on specific page post, our bot reply him via personal message or atleast our bot introduce himself in front of user e.g: if anyone comment on post ***'what is the price of this product?'*** so bot reply him in personal message ***'Hi dear customer this product is of $20'*** or atleast introduce himself in front of customer ***'Hi Dear customer I'm here to help you, Please ask me if you want to know anything'***

currently i have developer a bot using Api.ai and deployed to my facebook page and it is working perfectly please have a look here: https://www.messenger.com/t/inziChat

but i'm unable to reply user comments via this bot, even dont have any idea how to do it, i dont have trigger when user comment

Comment: The API endpoint for that would be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/object/private_replies Whether Api.ai supports that - you’d have to ask them ...

Comment: do you have done something like my requirement?

Comment: i mean how can i trigger some code when user comment, if i can trigger some code or rest api on comment i can do it with your solution

Comment: You’ll need to subscribe for webhook updates for the pages feed.

Comment: can you refer me to any blog or article referring to subscribing that webhook, or refer to some code example regarding to subscribing webhook

Comment: I believe in your ability to type “facebook webhook” into Google yourself ...

Comment: i already done it and get to this doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks
but unable to understand
so i need some good help

Comment: I recommend to read this article first https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic